# is it possible to use apache mahout without hadoop dependency?

Tags: java, hadoop, machine-learning, dependency-management, mahout

Is it possible to use Apache mahout without any dependency to Hadoop.

I would like to use the mahout algorithm on a single computer by only including the mahout library inside my Java project but i dont want to use hadoop at all since i will be running on a single node anyway.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Not all of Mahout depends on Hadoop, though much does. If you use a piece that depends on Hadoop, of course, you need Hadoop. But for example there is a substantial recommender engine code base that does not use Hadoop.

You can embed a local Hadoop cluster/worker in a Java program.

Comment: With Mahout 0.10 this just doesn't seem possible anymore. I'm trying to use the KMeans or FuzzyKMeans algorithms and they seem completely tied up in Hadoop. All I want to do is cluster some 2D (lat/longs actually) data points and having to rely on the hadoop file system seems extremely inefficient for the one-off operation I want it for.

Answer (score 11):

Definitely, yes. In the [Mahout Recommender First-Timer FAQ](https://mahout.apache.org/users/recommender/recommender-first-timer-faq.html) they advise against starting out with a Hadoop-based implementation (unless you know you're going to be scaling past 100 million user preferences relatively quickly).

You can use the implementations of the [Recommender interface](https://builds.apache.org/job/Mahout-Quality/javadoc/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/recommender/Recommender.html) in a pure-Java fashion relatively easily. Or place one in the servlet of your choice.

Technically, Mahout *has* a Maven dependency on Hadoop. But you can use recommenders without the Hadoop JARs easily. This is described in the first few chapters of Mahout in Action - you can download the [sample source code](http://www.manning.com/owen/) and see how it's done - look at the file `RecommenderIntro.java`.

However, if you're using Maven, you would need to exclude Hadoop manually - the dependency would look like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
        <artifactId>mahout-core</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The link mentioned in the answer does not direct to an article which can be read. [Mahout Recommender First-Timer FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/recommender-first-timer-faq.html) Can you please see to that?